# Fresh numerical methods for numerically solving linear PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am looking for fresh (up-to-date) and good methods for numerically solving linear PDEs (or system of PDEs)? I know that selecting the method depends on the type of the equation. But I am not capable of to select method. Please share your valuable and comprehensive viewpoint about this topic.

Let me know fresh methods for linear PDEs. I want to acquire background and general framework. So, it doesn' t matter type of Pde ( hyperbolic, elliptic, parabolic) for me. I am open to all numerical methods for all type PDEs.

Best regards.

Comment: The question is currently very broad... What method it's best to use depends on the PDE in question, if it's a boundary value problem or not, the domain etc. etc. etc. A good book that lists several methods with numerical examples for implementation is ["Numerical recipies"](https://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf)